# How can i fix the 'key error' in this python/pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame

Hi so i am creating a program that creates a random map using pictures i have created and then allows a user to move a character along the screen, i am trying to test it but keep getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\The map maker.py", line 89, in 
>       display.blit(tiles[dmap[row][column]], (column*tileSize,row*tileSize))
>   KeyError: Surface(40x40x32 SW)

If you could look at my code and show me how to fix it i will be very grateful. Thank you

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
MUD = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
MOUNTAIN = 3
pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeons and Dragons')
pygame.display.set_icon (pygame.image.load ('mountain.png'))
tiles = { #Creates a dictionary that links each picture to the type of ground
        MUD : pygame.image.load ('mud.png'),
        GRASS : pygame.image.load ('grass.png'),
        WATER : pygame.image.load ('water.png'),
        MOUNTAIN : pygame.image.load ('mountain.png')
        }
tileSize = 20
mapWidth = 30
mapHeight = 20
treasure = pygame.image.load ('treasure.png')
key = pygame.image.load ('key.png')
player = pygame.image.load ('player.png')
pposition = [0,0] # sets players start position
dmap = [[random.choice(tiles) for w in range(mapWidth)] for h in range (mapHeight)]
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode ((mapWidth*tileSize, mapHeight*tileSize))
while True:#if the user quits the game closes
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and pposition[0] < mapWidth -1:
                pposition[0] += 1
                num = random.randint (1-100) # chooses a random number between 1 and 100
                if num <= 10:
                    health -10 #if num is less than 10 than an enemy attacks and user loses health
                if health <= 0: # if the user loses all health then game is over
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            if event.key == K_LEFT and pposition[0] > 0: 
                pposition[0] -=1
                num = random.randint (1-100)
                if num <= 10:
                    health -10
                if health <= 0:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_UP and pposition[1] > 0: 
                pposition[1] -=1
                num = random.randint (1-100)
                if num <= 10:
                    health -10
                if health <= 0:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_DOWN and pposition[1] < mapHeight -1:
                pposition[1] +=1
                num = random.randint (1-100)
                if num <= 10:
                    health -10
                if health <= 0:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
    for row in range (mapHeight):
        for column in range(mapWidth):
            display.blit(tiles[dmap[row][column]], (column*tileSize,row*tileSize))
            display.blit(player,(pposition[0]*tileSize,pposition[1]*tileSize))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is all over the place and it really really really matters in Python.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, however, it is still coming up with a key error

Comment: see my anwser below

Comment: edited your indentation a bit more, it should be better now. Btw your `random.randint` calls are wrong, they should be `random.randint(1, 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error here;

```
for row in range (mapHeight):
    for column in range(mapWidth):
        display.blit(tiles[dmap[row][column]], (column*tileSize,row*tileSize))  # wrong
        display.blit(player,(pposition[0]*tileSize,pposition[1]*tileSize))
```

It should be like this;

```
for row in range (mapHeight):
    for column in range(mapWidth):
        display.blit(dmap[row][column], (column*tileSize,row*tileSize))  # fixed
        display.blit(player,(pposition[0]*tileSize,pposition[1]*tileSize))
```